# "greeked" text in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to "greek" HTML text, to obscure it using css and/or javascript, as shown in here:
[image: greek text sample]

All the columns have normal text. The 2nd, 3rd and 4th columns have "greeked" text. Clicking on them shows normal text, and "greeks" the first column.
What I need is that the characters somehow get replaced by squares, as shown in the picture, or a similar symbol. This way, they are hidden, but the text length, the words, paragraphs, everything is preserved.

Comment: Not sure if each letter has equal width, but u can write script to create greekText from orig text by regex (to *) perhaps, and insert display:none in DOM. Then some trigger to greek() and ungreek(). Cool assignment :)

Comment: Could the letters be blurred instead of squares?

Comment: If you want to preserve the text length and positioning, you could write a script that wraps each letter in a `span` and set the `color` and the `background-color` of the `span` to the same colour.

Comment: you could regex replace with the &#9632; character.  (medium square) - `string.replace(/(.)/g, "&#9632;");`

Comment: One question: how do you display the texts in those divs (with `<p>`, `´<span>`, 'plain' text)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to do this in css. [Blokk font](http://blokkfont.com/) is free and includes a web-font you can load via @font-face. You could then swap the font with an added (or removed) active class, or with javascript on whichever animation you want.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a custom font where every character is a square. Then you can switch out between a readable font and the custom font by changing the CSS style. The drawback would be that the user could copy the text and paste it in a text-editor to make it visible.

Another option would be to substitute the content strings itself. Store the content of each column in javascript, not in HTML. In the `.onload` handler you generate an obfuscated version of each string where every non-whitespace character is replaced with the unicode character `■` (codepoint 0x25a0). Then you assign to the `.innerHTML` of each div either the obfuscated or the unobfuscated version.

This option would still allow cheating by looking at the sourcecode, though. When you want the text to be completely inaccessible to the user before they are allowed to see it, you won't get around a server-sided solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would still be visible in the source and from copy/pasting. Unless that doesn't matter.

Comment: @SamHolmes I've added a 2nd option where this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: @Sam: pretty much under any situation with JavaScript modification of a page the underlying source-code remains viewable, surely?

Comment: @DavidThomas Meaning the only way to hide the data is to start with it obscured and to have the JS be able to decrypt it, correct?

Comment: I am inclined to agree with you. You could obfuscate it without a complicated MySQL setup, just use PHPs `file_get_contents()` function and retrieve the data from a text file through jQuery's `$.ajax()`. Of course, you _could_ also do it with MySQL, but unless obfuscating the source is _very_ important, there is no need to go that far.

Comment: When the source would be really sensitive I wouldn't even give the user a version where word lengths are visible, because this alone could leak critical information under some circumstances. That's really not worth the UI gimmick.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery would make this easier, so here's my jQuery solution that will greek the text onmouseout. Not exactly what you want, but it will be very similar

```
$('#div').on('mouseover',function(){
     $(this).css('color','transparent');
     $(this).css('text-shadow','0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)');
}).on('mouseout',function(){
     $(this).css('color','black');
     $(this).css('text-shadow','none');
});
```

Comment: `this` inside a jQuery event handler refers to the `DOMElement`, not the jQuery object. So you will need to wrap `this` in a jQuery constructor for `.css()` to work: `$(this)...`

Answer (score 0):

you could regex replace every character in each text container with the ■ character. (medium square) -

```
string.replace(/(.)/g, "&#9632;");
```

Comment: You first just get the text in a var.  Then just copy it into another var that you will replace the chars with square.  The first text var is still there.